# $n$-th derivative of Beta function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions

We pretty much know nothing about the high order derivatives of the Beta function. Well, we known for the example some recursive formulae for $\Gamma^{(n)}(1)$ as well as $\Gamma^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ but that is all. Yesterday , I encountered the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^n x}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )^m}\, {\rm d}x$$

As it can easily be seen , we have that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )^m}\, {\rm d}x ={\rm B}^{(1)} \left ( \frac{1}{2}, m- \frac{1}{2} \right ) \implies  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^n x}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )^m}\, {\rm d}x = {\rm B}^{(n)} \left ( \frac{1}{2}, m- \frac{1}{2} \right )$$

The question is whether or not we can express that last $n$-th derivative in a closed form - most likely in an inductive form. I guess it will be difficult but with mathematics you never know.

Comment: Since $B(x,y)$ has two arguments, you need to specify what you mean with $n^{th}$ derivative. Here are some formulas that might help:
http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta/20/

Comment: This derivative is respect to $x$. You differentiate $n$ times the formula:

$${\rm B} \left ( x, m-x \right )= m \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2x-1}}{\left ( 1+t^2 \right )^m}\, {\rm d}t$$

and then you just plug in $x=1/2$ so that you kill that $t$.

Comment: Then you have the derivatives of
$B(x,m-x)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(m-x)}{\Gamma(m)}$
i.e. the $n^{th}$ derivative of two gamma functions, which can be handled with the higher order product rule: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: In a sense yes. By the way I had totally forgotten about the General Liebniz Rule. If you desire, you may post it as an answer. I think it covers me.

Comment: Actually I am going ahead and posting it my self. Also, I'll add more details for this kind of integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote with

$$f(n, m)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^n x}{(1+x^2)^m}\, {\rm d}x$$

It is quite straigtforward to note that:

$$f(n, 1)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^n x}{1+x^2}\, {\rm d}x = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &,  &{\rm odd} \\ 
 2n! \beta(n+1)&, &{\rm even} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Here $\beta$ denotes the [Beta dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

On the other hand

$$f(1,m)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )^m}= {\rm B}^{(1)} \left ( \frac{1}{2}, m - \frac{1}{2} \right )= \frac{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right ) \Gamma \left ( m- \frac{1}{2} \right )  \bigg[ \psi^{(0)}\left ( \frac{1}{2}\right) - \psi^{(0)} \left ( m- \frac{1}{2} \right )  \bigg]}{m^2 \Gamma(m)}$$

Using gammatester's comment for the more general result, that is for $f(n,m)$ using [Liebniz's general rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) we have that:

$$f(n, m)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^n x}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )^m}\, {\rm d}x = {\rm B}^{(n)} \left ( \frac{1}{2}, m- \frac{1}{2} \right )= \frac{1}{m^2  \Gamma(m)}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \Gamma^{(k)} \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{(n-k)} \left ( m- \frac{1}{2} \right )$$

Of course for $\Gamma^{(n)} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)$ we have the following reduction formula:

$$\Gamma^{(n+1)}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )= -\left ( \gamma +2 \log 2 \right ) \Gamma^{(n)} \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right ) +n ! \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\left ( n-k \right )!} \left ( 2^{k+1}-1 \right )\zeta(k+1) \Gamma^{(n-k)}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )$$